# Compare two For Each lists in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a small problem.
I have two for each routines. One gives me all foldernames in the current folder. The other gives me all window names opened. Both are saving the results in a String. One with newlines, the other with ~, so I can loop through both and get all the items one by one.

This is the part:

```
    Dim Folders As String
    For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Data\")
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        Folders = Folders & dirInfo.Name & "~"
    Next

    Dim FolderList() As String = Folders.Split("~")

    Dim p As Process
    Dim Windows As String
    For Each p In Process.GetProcesses
        Windows = Windows & vbNewLine & p.MainWindowTitle.ToString
    Next
    Windows = LineTrim(Windows)
```

This works. But now, I want to compare them.
***I only want to get the Folders, where a window exists, which contains the foldername.***

For example, I have 3 folders: Test1,Test2,Test3.
I have one Window opened: "Test1 - Window"

Now I only want to get "Test1" as Result once.
I got it working so far, but I get "Test1" 3 times, because there are 3 folders. Because I am creating new Windows by this info, my function spams new windows..

This is the whole function:

```
Dim Folders As String
    For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Data\")
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        Folders = Folders & dirInfo.Name & "~"
    Next
    Dim str As String() = Folders.Split("~")
    For Each Folder As String In str

        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Data\" & Folder & "\" & "Status.txt")) Then
                Dim StartTime As String = Inireader.WertLesen("Settings", "StartTime", My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Data\" & Folder & "\Time.ini")
                Dim StopTime As String = Inireader.WertLesen("Settings", "StopTime", My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Data\" & Folder & "\Time.ini")
                If (IsInTime(StartTime, StopTime) = True) Then

                    Dim p As Process
                    Dim Windows As String
                    For Each p In Process.GetProcesses
                        Windows = Windows & vbNewLine & p.MainWindowTitle.ToString
                    Next
                    Windows = LineTrim(Windows)
                    Dim Ar() As String = Split(Windows, Environment.NewLine)
                    For Each Window As String In Ar
                        If sX.ToString.Contains(Window & "  - python  " & My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Data\" & Window& "\" & Window & ".py") Then ''''The Spam cause line
                        Else
                            Dim Path = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Data\" & Folder & "\" & Folder & ".py"
                            Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
                            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
                            startInfo.Arguments = "/k " & "title " & Folder & " & python " & Path
                            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Data\" & Folder & "\"
                            Process.Start(startInfo)

                        End If
                    Next
                End If
        End If
    Next
```

I can´t shorten it very much..
Could you help me out?
Thank you :)
Best regards!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DavidWilson Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777) and use caution when closing questions or making referrals. This question says: _Now I only want to get "Test1" as Result once. I got it working so far, but I get "Test1" 3 times, because there are 3 folders._ — which means that the code is not working correctly, and thus off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: What is `sX`? It's a little difficult to tell what's causing that `If` you flag to not work it we don't know what it's working with. As a separate comment, adding some comments on what you're trying to do with each step A) will help you keep your logic straight; B) will help you when you have to come back to this code at some point in the future; C) will help us understand your line of thought more clearly